Preventing Block Drawer Auto-Hide When On-Screen Keyboard is Active on Mobile Devices - Moodle Boost Theme
I am developing a dictionary block plugin for Moodle LMS using the Merriam-Webster API. The plugin works, but I encounter an issue on mobile devices. When I begin typing, the block drawer automatically hides, as shown below:

I believe the issue lies within the theme. The default Moodle theme, Boost, is available for free when you install Moodle on localhost. If you would like to see my plugin, you can check it out here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sownMmP9eScrU40tICskq-kPmvAi4j5k/view?usp=sharing
I'm using Moodle version 4.1.10
I need help, please help.
The block drawer remains open when the user inputs some keywords.
